# Error messages on UI for 4xx and 5xx server errors

Tags: manual-testing, validation, data-validation

I have to test two scenarios when due to some action **unexpected** 400 and 500 server errors have been thrown and the proper message appeared on the client for each of the errors.

When I try to edit the request via Fiddler and send it to server, I receive a correct error and everything is good on a server side. But editing and resending request is not affecting a client side, which make it's difficult to verify the full requirement.

Is there a way to simulate 400 and 500 server errors that will affect UI at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a freeware tool like [loopback](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/let-loopback-do-it-a-walkthrough-of-the-node-api-framework-you-ve-been-dreaming-of) to test client-side JavaScript. The error needs to be generated on the server-side so create a toy localhost server to send canned responses back to the browser.  Learning loopback shouldn't be that hard; something for a Saturday afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution by using [Burp proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) tool that helped me to bypass JS validation on a client, intercept the request that has been sent to the server, alter it and forward back to server. 
That way I was able to test exactly what I needed.